# Invalid static_cast from type <unresolved overloaded function type>

Tags: c++, function-pointers, static-cast

I have written the following function to apply various math operations to each element of a vector:

```
namespace MYFUNCTION
{
    template<class T>
    std::vector<T> eop(const std::vector<T> &v1, T (*f)(T))
    {
        std::vector<T> v2(v1.size());
        for(int ii = 0; ii < v1.size(); ii++)
        {
            v2[ii] = (*f)(v1[ii]);
        }
        return v2;
    }
}
```

I have also overloaded the `cosh()` function for `std::vector` parameters:

```
namespace MYFUNCTION
{
    template<class T>
    std::vector<T> cosh(const std::vector<T> v1)
    {
        return eop(v1,static_cast<T (*)(T)>(&std::cosh));
    }
}
```

If I use this function for type `double` every thing is fine. If I use `std::complex<double>` instead I get a compiler error.

```
std::vector<double> a(2);
a[0] = 1.0;
a[1] = 2.0;
std::cout << MYFUNCTION::cosh(a) << std::endl; // Works fine.

std::vector<std::complex<double> > b(2);
b[0] = 1.0 + std::complex<double>(0.0,1.0);
b[1] = 2.0;
std::cout << MYFUNCTION::cosh(b) << std::endl; // Compiler error.
```

The compiler error is:

```
error: invalid static_cast from type ‘<unresolved overloaded function type>’ to type ‘std::complex<double> (*)(std::complex<double>)’
```

EDIT:
This is the what the `cosh` function looks like in `complex.h`:

```
template<class T> complex<T> cosh (const complex<T>& x);
```

This is the what the `cosh` function looks like in `cmath.h`:

```
double cosh (double x);
```

I have included both `complex.h` and `cmath.h`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `std::cosh` for `std::complex<T>` is a function template, `&std::cosh` doesn't make sense to the compiler because `std::cosh` is **not** a function, it is a *template* of family of functions. You need to write another overload to handle this case:

```
#include <complex> //it is where std::cosh<T> is defined

template<class T>
std::vector<std::complex<T>> cosh(std::vector<std::complex<T>> const & v1)
{
    typedef std::complex<T> cosh_type( std::complex<T> const &);
    return eop(v1, static_cast<cosh_type*>(&std::cosh<T>) );
}
```

By the way, pass the argument by *reference* to avoid unnecessary copies.

Hope that helps.

Comment: @leemes: that was a typo.